# Python heatmap equation

Tags: python, heatmap, equation

I need help trying to translate an equation into Python so I can generate a heatmap out of it. It describes the temperature distribution of a plate centered over the x-axis with the left edge on the y-axis. The plate is x=a wide and y=b/2 tall over the x-axis, and y=-b/2 under the x-axis. The top and bottom of the plate are held at 120 degrees and the sides are held at 20 degrees. The link to see the image of the equation is below.

How would I go about making this into code that Python can recognize?

[image: Temperature distribution equation]

Comment: What is the name of this equation?

Answer (score 1):

```
from mpmath import *
T = 20 + nsum(lambda n: (-1)**n * (400/ (n * pi)) * (cosh((n*pi*y)/a) / cosh((n*pi*b)/2*a)) * sin((n*pi*x)/a) , [1,inf])
```

Comment: Change (400/n * pi) to (400/n/pi)

Comment: The code doesn't work. First, what am I importing from mpmath? I converted everything to numpy, but it still tells me that a list object cannot be interpreted as an integer. Here is my numpy conversion of the above suggestion: T = 20 + np.sum(lambda n: (-1)**n * (400/ (n * np.pi)) * (np.cosh((n*np.pi*y)/a) / np.cosh((n*np.pi*b)/2*a)) * np.sin((n*np.pi*x)/a) , [1,np.inf])

Comment: @billyyank `nsum, cosh, pi, inf` has been imported from mpmath and there is no summation function from n=1 to inf in numpy. So the code np.sum gives error.